# Struts2 xml validation using external file

Tags: xml, validation, properties, struts2

I have another struts 2 related question. I'm currently using Struts xml validation to validate form input. I want to load the regex from an external file, config.ini. The java class calls it properly, I already tested it in demo, however something is not working in the xml validation, it doesn't seem to load the regex string.

```
TrustedAction-validation.xml
     <field-validator type="regex">
                <param name="expression">
                <![CDATA[@net.codejava.framework.opensips.regexValidator@getRegex()]]>
                </param>
                <message>
                    Please enter a valid IP.
                </message>
            </field-validator>
```

I also added the required line to the struts.xml file:

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

My getRegex() method works as I said, spits out the regex from the config file, however I feel like I am doing something wrong in the validation.xml. CDATA doesn't seem to load the method.

And here is my folder structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIRhs.jpg

Is it even possible to do it like this? I don't really want to switch to java validation.

Comment: Is it possible to call a java function to return a string and feed it into the validator? if so, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are doing everything wrong, because you need a validator to parse regex expression into the code.

Comment: The regex is returned by the Java method that I am calling

Comment: Solved it by just doing it the java way. You can apparently use the xml validator combined with the java validator in struts 2 which is cool, no issues so far with it. Plus doing it the way I was trying to is a not recommended as this was phased out post version 2.5.something.

Comment: I didn't get what are you saying. Who recommended you not to use the programmatic validation?

Comment: I thought I made everything pretty clear.

[@net.codejava.framework.opensips.regexValidator@getRegex()]

This is bad.

Normal java validation is good.

Comment: Sure, better to create a custom validator and use it in xml config